# Where can I find the SDK for the Mifare Ultralight EV1?

Tags: c++, mifare

I am trying to develop with the Mifare Ultralight EV1 in c++. I am a beginner in the area. Working with the ISO14443A standard is totally new for me. I saw that Mifare has abstracted a lot of processes, like the anticollision. Since I'm working with Mifare Ultralight EV1, I want to make us of this. I found documentation of NXP advertising the SDK, however I cannot find it anywhere. Can anyone point me in the right direction? I have already looked at the NXP and Mifare websites, and ofcourse googled about it alot.

Comment: https://www.mifare.net/en/products/tools/taplinx/

Comment: Can I use this to develop only for Android?

Comment: I have no clue, but it's the SDK afaik.